# The distance in Lobachevski (Hyperbolic) space

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I need to find the distance from the point provided in the hyperboloid model with a vector $x$ where $\langle x,x\rangle=-1$ to the hyperplane $H_e$ with a normal vector $e$, where $\langle e,e\rangle=1$.

I have some kind of solution it is here:

$\rho$ is the distance, and $r_e$ is defined as $r_e: x \mapsto x - 2\langle e,x\rangle e$.

1. $\rho(x,H_e) = \frac12\rho(x,r_e(x))$
2. $\cosh(\rho(x,r_e(x))) = -\langle x,r_e(x)\rangle =
   -\langle x, x - 2\langle e,x\rangle e\rangle = 1 + 2\langle e,x\rangle^2$
3. $\cosh(2\times \frac12\rho(x,r_e(x))) =
   1 + 2 \times \sinh^2(\frac12\rho(x,r_e(x)))$

Hence, $\sinh(\rho(x,H_e)) = \lvert\langle e,x\rangle\rvert$.

Is it correct? Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: Sorry, could you, please, note what is not very clear.

$\rho$ is the distance, sh,ch - hyperbolic sin and cos

Comment: Ok, i agree with sinh and cosh. 1/2? what did i mean? Well, it is needed, because of the formula cosh 2x = 1 + 2 sinh^2 x

Comment: Sorry, take a look again: I just wonder if I interpreted it correctly. And what is $H_e$? The hyperplane normal to $e$?

Comment: Yes, it is OK.
And yes, $H_e$ is a hyperplane with e normal vector to it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question (and I hope my edit to it was correct), you intend $r_e$ to denote a reflection in $H_e$. So this is my main concern, whether that operation is really a reflection with respect to the hyperbolic metric. It is easy to see that every point on $H_e$ itself will remain fixed under this operation, since $\langle e,x\rangle=0$ for these. In addition to this, you need the property that ideal points (i.e. light-like vectors) will be preserved:

$$\langle y,y\rangle=0\;\implies\;\langle r_e(y),r_e(y)\rangle=0$$

When I first posted this answer, I proposed a counterexample. But I must have gotten my math wrong, in more than one place. Now I am convinced that this is actually true, due to the following consideration:

$$
\langle r_e(x),r_e(x)\rangle =
\bigl\langle x-2\langle e,x\rangle e,x-2\langle e,x\rangle e\bigr\rangle =
\langle x,x\rangle
-4\langle e,x\rangle^2
+4\langle e,x\rangle^2\langle e,e\rangle =
\langle x,x\rangle
$$

So a point on the hyperboloid gets correctly mapped to a point on the hyperboloid. Therefore I trust that $r_e$ is indeed a reflection. After that, everything looks watertight to me.

As for simplification: neither the formula nor its deduction seem to leave a lot of room for simplifications. There might be slightly shorter ways to write down the deduction, depending on what prior knowledge you may assume.

Comment: It is not necessary that (e,x) is 0. If e= (1,0,0), x = (1,1,1). (x,x) = -1, (x,e) = 1?

Comment: And what is with your vectors? (e,e) and (y,y)?

Comment: How do you get, that if (y,y) = 0, that ($r_e$y,$r_e$y)=0. These "ideal points", what do you mean, when say ideal.

Comment: @Jerry: $\langle e,x\rangle=0$ iff $x$ lies in $H_e$. That's the incidence condition for the plane. For my vectors you can compute that $-e_1^2+e_2^2+e_3^2=-1$ so $e$ is timelike normal and $-y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=0$ so $y$ is lightlike. Consider points along a line at equal distance.

Comment: @Jerry: To understand ideal points, forget for a moment the normality condition. You can consider any timelike vector as a homogeneous representative of a point on the hyperboloid. In that sense, a lighlike vector represents a point “at infinity”, which you might obtain in the limit by taking steps of equal size along a line. In the same spirit, I imagine spacelike vectors as being “beyond infinity” or “even more infinite”. These concepts are even more readily apparent if you work in the Beltrami-Klein model instead of the hyperboloid.

Comment: @Jerry: To phrase it differently: lighlike vectors form the light cone and as such are asymptotes of your hyperboloid. A transformation which does not fix the light cone will not preserve the hyperboloid. So it won't form a bijection between hyperbolic points, so it cannot be a hyperbolic isometry, so it cannot be a hyperbolic reflection.

Comment: For your y, i received $r_e$(y) = (-1,0,1) ,so ($r_e$(y),$r_e$(y))=0. I don't know what was your problem, but that does break 1), yet.

Comment: So, i think your answer is wrong...